# Increasing model simulation speed with big number of agents/transporters Anylogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I've a question. In my model I want to model patients/employees in a hospital environment as agents. Due to the big amount of patients/employees in the hospital (>4000), my model runs very slow (which is logical, I know). Because I want the patients employees to block eachother and AGVs, I let them move by a transporterfleet (which has >5000 capacity), by doing this method I can make it possible to let them block eachother.

Now what I want is that when the patient or employees arrive to the location departments they disappear for hours/minutes as long as there appointment or workschedule is saying to them. The most perfect is to just delete them for example 4 hours of runtime, so that I will only have the moving agents in my model, is there a way to do this? So that when a patient/employee arrives at an appointment, the agent and transport disappears for 4 hours and returns after this delay, keeping in mind that it should speed up the run-speed of my simulation (otherwise I just can use a delay block, but than my model keeps very slow). The transporters are making the model really slow.

Or perhaps another method will be better to model the patients and employees with the feature that they are blocking AGVs? An option which I should think of is that an moving agent is constantly checking if there is an agent close to him every second, but I do not know if this will be speed up the runtime or just will slow it down even more with >4000agents.

Or another option is that I only let the AGVs check if there are agents around them every second just by coding(this will only be around 40 agents).

Also you see that it is only using 5% of my memory data..
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: This a tough question that I have also faced. I would suggest by profiling your model, by using [this](https://visualvm.github.io/) fee tool. Let's first see where are your bottlenecks. Sometimes they appear in places where you can't imagine.

Comment: Thanks @YasharAhmadov, I download it, it seems that my problem is in the metaspace size. Since it is using 39mb and my max is 40mb. Also when i delete my transporter fleet and just let them move, my model is way faster, so I know where my problems are.

Comment: Hi, I strongly doubt that you need to model actual patient/AGV blockings if there are >4000 patients in your hospital. Strongly suggest you review what level of detail various parts of your model require. Do not add details for the sake of it :)

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin, I've decided to indeed do it in another way

Comment: Without knowing the architecture of your design I would also suggest you check out this blog post on why you should java classes where possible instead of agents - https://www.theanylogicmodeler.com/post/why-use-java-classes-in-anylogic